# Best practice for choosing ids when get data from another system

Tags: sql

My system is using a 3rd party service to handle the data and now I have to call API from that 3rd party and store the data to our database. I would like to ask what is the best practice for the ids in this case?

For example, I call transaction API and the id returned from the 3rd party is 123456, I have 2 solutions and which solution should I choose from the 2 below

1. id = 123456
2. id = 1 (incremental number), 3rd_party_id = 123456

For the 1st solution, I just need to use their id as my system id.

For the 2nd solution, I need to create id as incremental number and create a new column named 3rd_party_id to store the 3rd party id.

In my opinion, the 1st solution is good enough since their ids are unique. But I would like to ask for more ideas about this case. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:  it depends.  But what should you be thinking about?  Here are some considerations.

Is the third-party id some convoluted long string?  If so, just for performance reasons, you want your own id, because integers are more efficient for foreign key references.

Is the third-party id some sort of PII (personally identifiable information)?  If so, you probably want to mask it, and an internal id is a very handy solution.

Is your definition of the entity 100% tied to the third party?  If no, you may find that you want to combine or split existing ids.  If that is the case, then an internal id is handy.

Is the third-party id the "canonical" way of referring to the thing?  If so you might want to use it.  For instance, I think it is fine to use ISO country codes as a country id.  They are standard and rarely change.

Will the third-party id be used across multiple databases as "the thing"?  If so, you might want to keep it as the key, so you don't have  equivalent ids proliferating across multiple databases.

These are just some things to think about.  There are no doubt others as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! You provided me a lot of useful information!

Answer (score 3):

I differ from the previous answer. I almost always would prefer to have my internal ID as well.

The thing is... you don't have control of the external ID. It may change over time without you knowing -- intentionally or due to an application defect on the external organization. There can be a myriad of other issues that can cause instability in the external organization and you don't want to be exposed to that.

In order to keep my app stable I would use my own ID and I will store the external ID as well. This way if the external application fails -- o worst, it produces wrong data -- I can always fix the data in my database by rerunning "fixing processes" or by reapplying data. But, if I already merged external records it won't be easy to "unmerge" them.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! That's a very good point to think about!